# Convert Mysql statement into Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Since mysql doesn't allow symbol or parameter in views, I want to put my sql statement direct in my controller. But I keep getting an error.

MySQL statement:

```
SELECT `nokp`, `tarikh_hadir`, @kod_bah := IF(`kod_bah` IS NULL, @kod_bah,`kod_bah`) 'kod_bah'
FROM (SELECT * FROM v_04_harifullkerjawarga_01 ORDER BY `tarikh_hadir`) t1,(SELECT @kod_bah :=0) t2
where nokp = 8201;
```

I try to convert in laravel as below:

```
$results = DB::connection('cams')
    ->table('v_04_harifullkerjawarga_01')
    ->select(DB::raw("SELECT `nokp`, `tarikh_hadir`, @kod_bah := IF(`kod_bah` IS NULL, @kod_bah,`kod_bah`) 'kod_bah'"))
    ->select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM v_04_harifullkerjawarga_01 ORDER BY `tarikh_hadir`) t1"),
    DB::raw("(SELECT @kod_bah :=0) t2"))
    ->where('nokp','=',8201
    ->get();
```

But, I get an error. Please someone can help me solve this.

My error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM v_04_harifullkerjawarga_01 ORDER BY `tarikh_hadir`) t1, (SELECT @k' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT * FROM v_04_harifullkerjawarga_01 ORDER BY `tarikh_hadir`) t1, (SELECT @kod_bah :=0) t2 from `v_04_harifullkerjawarga_01` where `nokp` = 8201)
```

Comment: Can you also add the error message to your question?

Comment: @Peppermintology, i edit my question by added the error.

Comment: look at your sql error, of course it is not working. You have to clean up the mess first I guess with double select. that's not a right way to use select of course